# how to run jar file and include images?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

it's my first time making a .jar file run. at first try, i can run the .jar file but the images doesn't show up. now, i only transferred the location of my java project, and the .jar file won't run anymore. can someone help me with these problems...

1) where do i put all the images, should i put them inside the package, or can it be just inside the src? if i should put them inside the package, can i put them in a folder inside?

2) currently, my images are inside a folder in the package (src\package\folder) and is instantiated as...

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("folder/image.png"));
```

when i run the program in eclipse, it works...this, however, throws me NullPointerException error with (Unknown Source) when i run the .jar file through cmd

3) does the directory where i save the .jar file be the cause? or is the location of the .jar file unnecessary?

4) what should i choose between the 3 library handling when creating executable .jar file in eclipse?